# how to make the space between a multi-line link clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I want to link a sentence that's 3 lines long. It seems simple enough, but I can't figure out an elegant way to make the space between the lines clickable too. Here's my code:

```
<style>
    a {
        color: #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height:40px;
    }
</style>

<a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/>
consectetur adipiscing elit,<br/>
sed do eiusmod tempor</a>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbxyjdvb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put div (block) inside span (inline) element.
[Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Convert Anchor to `display: inline-block`, then user extra span to restore underlines in text.

html:

```
<a href="#"><span class="underline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/>
consectetur adipiscing elit,<br/>
    sed do eiusmod tempor</span></a>
```

css:

```
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height:40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.underline {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zbxyjdvb/9/

Comment: actually, I just realized that the width of the entire block is a link. that would be ok if it wasn't noticeable, but here's a more accurate representation of my copy: [http://jsfiddle.net/zbxyjdvb/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/zbxyjdvb/12/) is there a way to only link the text?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pseudo-elements to achieve this. So, HTML is not changed:

```
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/>
consectetur adipiscing elit,<br/>
sed do eiusmod tempor</a>
```

But, CSS is:

```
   a {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height:40px;
    position:relative;

}
a:before {

    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:400%;
    /*background-color:#666;*/

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zbxyjdvb/11/

Depending on your `a block` size, you will have to play with height a little...

Answer (score 1):

You could add vertical padding to the `a` element to increase the area it covers which is clickable, without affecting the layout, or making surrounding text clickable.

The amount of padding you need would be the difference between the line height and the font size.  In your case the line height is `40px` and font size `20px`, so you'd need `20px` of vertical padding to cover the gap.  You already have `5px` as bottom padding plus a `1px` border, so would need to add `14px` of top padding (as you can't increase the bottom padding without making the border appear lower).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sjwa7bf1/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap an `<a>` around a `<div>`.

```css
a {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/>
consectetur adipiscing elit,<br/>
    sed do eiusmod tempor
   </div>
</a>
```